# Plot date time in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new in Python and want to plot a set of data which includes time data with 2 columns of yyyy-mm-dd and hh:mm:ss
I found datetime function to be useful for this purpose but I was not able to plot my data using it.

Below is the first 5 rows of my data
I would like to plot Temp and QP versus time in separate windows:

```
        DATE      TIME      TEMP         QP
0  2018-08-4  15:18:49  209.3851  4045.4414
1  2018-08-4  15:18:50  209.3851  4045.4314
2  2018-08-4  15:18:51  209.3581  4045.4268
3  2018-08-4  15:18:52  209.3553  4045.4343
4  2018-08-4  15:18:53  209.3553  4045.4307
```

What I tried :

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from datetime 
import datetime 

dataset = pd.read_csv('pressuredata.csv', sep='\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+', engine="python") 
#print(dataset.head()) 
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset) 
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'] + ' ' + df['TIME']) 
df2 = df[["datetime","TEMP","QP"]] 
df2.set_index("datetime",inplace=True) 
print(df.head())
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? do you have some code to show?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple plotting based on your data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('k1.csv')
df['date-time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['DATE', 'TIME']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), 
axis=1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].plot('date-time', 'QP', data=df)
ax[1].plot('date-time', 'TEMP', data=df)
plt.show()
```